# AudioKit 5: Sequencing effects

Tags: swift, audio, audiokit

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to add effects to a new track in the sequencer just like you would with a instrument.

So far I haven’t been able to figure it out based on the docs, but the idea is to be able to sequence parameters for a selected effect just like you would with midi note information such as velocity, length and pitch/note for AudioKit instruments.
Say if you wanted to sequence a low pass filter; you would have access to sequence the cutoff frequency and resonance etc.

Any ideas if this is achievable with AudioKit?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could represent the parameter changes you want to sequence inside MIDI events, add those events to a [sequencer track](https://audiokit.io/docs/Classes/AKSequencerTrack.html), add the track to a sequencer and connect the sequencer track to a [callback instrument](https://audiokit.io/docs/Classes/AKCallbackInstrument.html). The callback instrument would change the low pass filter's parameters.

So the outline of the process would be:

`SequencerTrack -> Callback instrument -> Low pass filter's parameters`

It might not be an ideal solution because you would be calling a Swift function from the DSP and back into the DSP from Swift, but it's the only solution that comes to mind without writing your own custom DSP code.